# 2sxc. The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dnn9

When trying to go to the Apps List in 2sxc, or using the Visual Query Editor Run function, I am getting a 400 (Bad Request).

I am also experiencing a memory leak, but I'm not sure if this is the cause or something else.
It just happened around Saturday, and no one was on the site.

DNN 9.8.1
2sxc 12.10.0

Stack Trace:

```
The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at ToSic.Eav.Apps.AppState.MapDraftToPublished(Entity newEntity, Nullable`1 publishedId, Boolean log) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Core\Apps\State\AppState_DraftPublish.cs:line 38
   at ToSic.Eav.Apps.AppState.Add(Entity newEntity, Nullable`1 publishedId, Boolean log) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Core\Apps\State\AppState_Entities.cs:line 39
   at ToSic.Eav.Persistence.Efc.Efc11Loader.LoadEntities(AppState app, Int32[] entityIds) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Persistence.Efc\Efc11Loader_Entities.cs:line 97
   at ToSic.Eav.Persistence.Efc.Efc11Loader.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<Update>b__0() in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Persistence.Efc\Efc11Loader_App.cs:line 107
   at ToSic.Eav.Apps.AppState.Load(Action loader) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Core\Apps\State\AppState_Load.cs:line 41
   at ToSic.Eav.Persistence.Efc.Efc11Loader.Update(AppState app, AppStateLoadSequence startAt, Int32[] entityIds) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Persistence.Efc\Efc11Loader_App.cs:line 115
   at ToSic.Eav.Persistence.Efc.Efc11Loader.LoadBasicAppState(Int32 appId) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Persistence.Efc\Efc11Loader_App.cs:line 42
   at ToSic.Eav.Persistence.Efc.Efc11Loader.AppState(Int32 appId, Boolean ensureInitialized) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Persistence.Efc\Efc11Loader_App.cs:line 52
   at ToSic.Eav.Caching.AppsCacheBase.GetOrBuild(IAppIdentity appIdentity, String primaryLanguage) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Core\Caching\Apps\AppsCacheBase.cs:line 153
   at ToSic.Eav.Apps.App.Init(IAppIdentity appIdentity, Func`2 buildConfiguration, ILog parentLog) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Apps\App.cs:line 110
   at ToSic.Sxc.Apps.AppsRuntime.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<GetApps>b__0(KeyValuePair`2 a) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Apps\Parts\AppsRuntime.cs:line 67
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at ToSic.Sxc.WebApi.App.AppsBackend.Apps() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc.WebApi\App\AppsBackend.cs:line 25
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

I have been looking through the 2sxc tables trying to figure out what caused it. I also set the ToSIC_EAV_Entites.IsPublished to the last couple entities that were added on Friday evening, and it is still showing the error.

Comment: sorry, but based on this, and the fact that it's a fairly old version of 2sxc, it's just guessing. I highly recommend you upgrade to a v14 or even 16 LTS.